# How to define permissible options in route segment in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, url-routing, razor-pages

I have these URLs:

```
/entity/create
/entity/edit/6
```

And I want to limit my Razor Page to these two URLs.

I created this route, using `@page` directive:

```
@page "/companyInfo/{action}/{id?}";
```

And it works. But the problem is that it accepts all kind of values for `{action}` and `{id?}` segments.

I want to apply these limitations on this route:

1. `{actions}` should only take one of the `create` or `edit` values
2. `{id}` should not exist in `create` and should exist for `edit`.

In other words, I want to bind my Razor Page form, to two modes of creation and edition.

What should I do?

Comment: the pattern you write for `@page` is just to provide some more constraint (or to make it more friendly) on the route data. It is always mapped to `OnGet` or `OnGetAsync` handler. I'm not so sure how you use one same razor page for 2 URLs? If you define 2 pages, you can define different patterns (e.g: the first is `/companyInfo/edit/{id?}`, the second is `/companyInfo/create` - so that way you don't need any custom constraint here). Please add more details to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Create a page called Crud in your CompanyInfo folder and add a route template to the `@page` directive with a leading `/` so that it overrides the default route template:

`@page "/CompanyInfo/Create"`

Then use `AddPageRoute` in `Startup` to define an extra route template for the page:

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/CompanyInfo/Crud", "/CompanyInfo/Edit/{id:int}");
});
```

Ref: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#friendly-routes